# What is the difference between C++ Composite and Chain of Responsibility patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, c++

A [Composite](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/composite) delegates calculations of unknown depth to a virtual method.

A [Chain of Responsibility](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility) passes events to an arbitrary deep line of handlers.

Sounds the same to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many patterns have a lot of similarities, and often the differences can seem minuscule. Often a real life implementation might even include parts of multiple patterns. What is important is not whether you use a particular pattern, or whether it is implemented exactly as specified. What is important is that the pattern you actually use solves the problem you have.

The Composite and Chain of Responsibility patterns are very similar, and my guess is that the implementations will have a tendency to contain a bit of both. Having said that, I see subtle differences between the two.

1. Chain of Responsibility is crucially order dependent. The order of the handlers matters greatly, since any handler can choose to short-circuit the execution chain. That can potentially be viable for optimization, or for blocking further handling.
2. The Composite pattern description on the page you linked https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/composite actually contains a good illustration of this pattern and where it might be different. See the illustration from the page below:
   [image: Composite Pattern]
   In the illustration above the responsible class gets a request to calculate the price, consider if this request is sent to a box containing a lot of articles. The price of the box will be the sum of the prices of the individual items in it. So it iterates over the items and ask them to provide their price. Each of them could potentially be a smaller box wither items, which would cause them to iterate their list, and return the price.
3. Had this been a **Chain of Responsibility** implementation, then the first child had been asked to provide it's price, and the a reference to the next child had been provided to it. And then it would be the responsibility of the individual children to pass the request along. But then it would also be possible for the individual children to short circuit the process, and thus you wouldn't get the complete price.

So in the end:

**Chain of Responsibility**: The handler passes the request on to the next handler in the list, and also has complete control over whether to call the next handler.

**Composite**: The controller calling the handler calls the individual handlers, and thus the handlers will control their own handler, and whether to call their child handlers (if any), but not the next handler of the controller.

Comment: Mind note: 'Composite' == 'Multichild Chain of Responsibility'. Also they belong to different classes of patterns but that matters far less.

Answer (score 4):

Composite is for creating tree-like structures, which is a **structural** pattern.

Chain-of-responsibility is not, it is just about chaining operations, which is a **behavioral** pattern.

Sometimes, there may be operations in a Composite which delegate calculations down to the leafes of a tree in a recursive fashion. Those operations may be seen as a Chain-Of-Responsibility, and when you have a case like that, then it includes both patterns in one. But that does not make two very different patterns the same.